# How much does pre-PhD work affect chances in seeking academic jobs?

Tags: publications, phd, job-search, assistant-professor

I have completed the third year of my PhD studies in Electrical Engineering. So far, I have published a few conference papers during my PhD. However, I had several good journal and conference publications before my PhD studies, but they are not related to my current research topic. As I consider applying for academic positions, I am curious about how these earlier publications might affect my chances of securing a position. Will my pre-PhD publications be considered? Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

If they are within your field, they would have some weight. It isn't just your dissertation topic that is relevant in academic hiring. Professors take on lots of roles in academia and aren't expected to stay on one topic throughout a career.

For some jobs, say in teaching institutions, broader interests and experience might be a plus initially. And, almost everyone does some undergraduate teaching in any case, even in research oriented places.

But a lot more than this will be determinative of your success. Don't focus a lot on any single thing.